# How to search Calcurse calendar?

Tags: command-line, calendar

I am learning how to use the terminal-based Calcurse calendar.

There is a box to search but only words that are actually showing on the screen are found - i.e. not found if at some remote date (beyond 21 days).

Can anyone help me with this conundrum?

Many thanks
DB

Comment: You can send a bug report to calcurse@culot.org or to the author frederic@ culot.org see reference [here](http://culot.org/calcurse/manual_en.html)

Comment: Thank you very much - this is very useful information.

Comment: I've posted the comment as an answer if you'd be kind enough to accept it so anyone else with the same issue can easily find the information as there is no man page for this application. Thanks

Comment: Thank you - will do. I have emaied 'frederic' but have not yet received a reply. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bug reports can be sent to calcurse@culot.org or the author at  frederic@ culot.org

The documentation for the application can be found [here](http://culot.org/calcurse/manual_en.html)